# cannot get Nginx working for different location on the same root

Tags: nginx, configuration, nginx-location

I am just starting with nginx and trying to run different sites with a common root on the same port.

Imagine the file structure as follow:

```
rootPath/ -> website1-folder/index.html
         |
          -> website2-folder/index.html
```

I tried with the `location context` and the `root` directive inside that context, thus, my nginx.config looks like

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
    include mime.types;
    server{
        listen 4444;
        server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
        index index.html index.htm;
        location / { # this location did work :)
            return 404 "Not found!"; 
        }
        location /first { # hier I got 404
            root /home/websites/web1;
        }
        location /second { # hier I got 404
            root /home/websites/web2;
        }
    }
```

I also tried with the `alias` directive, thus my config file looks like:

```
        http {
        include mime.types;
        server{
            listen 4444;
            server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
            index index.html index.htm;
            root /home/websites;
            location / { # this location did work :)
                return 404 "Not found!"; 
            }
            location /first { # hier I got 404
                alias /web1; # the '/' refers to the root directive, right?
            }
            location /second { # hier I got 404
                alias /web2;
            }
        }
```

Strange enough, for me, is that I am sure, the location context correctly matched, since

```
location /second { 
         alias /web2;
         return 200 $uri; # this prints "/second" in the browser       
         }
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: Wrong - the `alias` directive does not refer to the `root` directive. Your question is confusing, but I think that changing `root` to `alias` in your first example, is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RichardSmith Just to clarify, the question in my second example meant to be: When I use `alias` directive in the `location context`, does the `/` refers to `root` directive of the `server context`? If so, this `/`  should refer basically to the folder 'websites', isn't?

Comment: If the parameter (of `root` or `alias`) begins with a `/`, it is an absolute path from the top of your file system. Otherwise, it is relative to some built in value of `nginx` where the "welcome to nginx" files are served.